# docker nestjs could not build

Tags: node.js, docker, nestjs

```
FROM node:latest as development
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=development
COPY . .
RUN npm run build


FROM node:latest as production
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY . .
COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/prisma ./prisma
COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run start:prod
```

Since I'm using a Mac m1 chip computer, I use the following command to build.

```
sudo docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64  -t swai-api .
```

But it was never built. It gives the following error.

[image]

Comment: Seems like a post-install instruction from `prisma` is causing an error, yeah?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with npm install. But it may be giving an error from prisma @JayMcDoniel

Comment: `path /usr/src/app/node_modules/prisma`, `command failed`, `command sh -c nnode scripts/install-entry.js`, yeah, looks like a prisma related issue, not necessarily NestJS

Comment: Looks like it's specifically an Out Of Memory exception.

Comment: You can have a look here https://github.com/Saluki/nestjs-template
nestjs version 8 with docker setup